# Python Sklearn Silhouette Coefficient

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I want to calculate the silhouette coefficient after performing partitional clustering. Since I am using a custom distance metric, can I input the distance matrix as input for sklearn  silhouette_score?

Answer (score 0):

If the distance matrix is used as the input array, metric should be set as `metric='precomputed'`

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html